# Use typescript conditional types to bind two type generically

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, conditional-types

With conditional types, I try to set up a type mapping rules from a known set of generic type `RequestType` to their corresponding `ResponseType` so that in `function myCache` it can deduce the correct `ResponseType` after narrowing down `RequestType` as the following example:

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEAlApgRwK7JgFwCoE8AHZARngG9R54AnZKAEwHsA7CfeDZGjgXngDk2IsngkBAblABfUKACWLbNwBmUMKJQxCrGMgLEylENQZRsUAFyDhxMZJlzw0OEjSYcB5ACYKVWvTMbBxcPPD8QiLw3g4gsiAKSqrqmlg6LHpevsam5lY2UTFScU4q6Cxg2PKs8IQ0itha6XokABR02rrI1k1dXiQAlH4JJSNlFVU1dQ29GT7taV09i3NZQ8aOI6C2orhMs5kiADwoXJ4iAHzhbmd4UcgAHsosDAinHneG8AD8bp2rIjI1la7ywn1Ej2erxuHyyPz+zX0Il81hYyAAbtwBsVQONKtUWPAALb4ADC6gAFsgTu4wV4Lgtbstbl4ADQBf56ax7A5I4g0lmXdb+eQqeCMj7wRQ4KAVZBMMWg86GYUmai1epKXltDqI7H+eLSIA)

code:

```
class RequestType1 {
  readonly query = 'type 1';
}

interface ResponseType1 {
  data: 'type 1';
}

class RequestType2 {
  readonly query = 'type 2';
}

interface ResponseType2 {
  data: 'type 2';
}

function printResponse1(response: ResponseType1) {

}

function printResponse2(response: ResponseType2) {

}


type ToResponseType<RequestType> = RequestType extends RequestType1 ? ResponseType1 : (RequestType extends RequestType2 ? ResponseType2 : never);

function myCache<RequestType>(request: RequestType, response: ToResponseType<RequestType>) {
  if (request instanceof RequestType1) {
    printResponse1(response);
  }
}
```

But in the narrow down if-block of `RequestType1` with `printResponse1`, it still gives error like:

```
Argument of type 'ResponseType1 | ResponseType2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ResponseType1'.
```

Can anyone tell how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Your code will only constrain what arguments can the function be called with and will not affect the interpretation of what they are within the function. This is because each parameter is a union type to begin with and the inference of one parameter type will not influence what the other type will be.

The best way to overcome this in your case would be to use a [Type Predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) which will allow you to decide the `response` type based on the `request`:

```
function isResponseType1(request: RequestType1 | RequestType2, response: ResponseType1 | ResponseType2): response is ResponseType1 {
  return request instanceof RequestType1;
}

function myCache(request: RequestType1 | RequestType2, response: ResponseType1 | ResponseType2): void {
  if (isResponseType1(request, response)) {
    printResponse1(response);
  }
}
```

Playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEAlApgRwK7JgFwCoE8AHZARngG9R54AnZKAEwHsA7CfeDZGjgXngDk2IsngkBAblABfUKACWLbNwBmUMKJQxCrGMgLEylENQZRsUAFyDhxMZJlzw0OEjSYcB5ACYKVWvTMbBxcPPD8QiLw3g4gsiAKSqrqmlg6LHpevsam5lY2UTFScU4q6Cxg2PKs8IQ0itha6XokABR02rrI1k1dXiQAlH4JJSNlFVU1dQ29GT7taV09i3NZQ8aOY%20WV1Szw8jCzmSJtdFw4y%20d4J-AAPm5XWQA0AZ1zy2-Hhndun-oi3gG1g6zVEB1%20oP6w2odGw6BoezOHmw%20wyFgqyCYKgeyP6xXioHGOxqAFt8ABhdQAC2QCyul1xN3uKEeAJeIKWEL6TK5qwBQPgADcmPIGND9tjWgcjv9DHTkeyVnoBut-NRpkoZaclcgBsVqPECSAyZSwDTWixkAB3HFYa5ygYvcjwMwWayROzieDSAZAA).